# Request json with c# api and ajax

Tags: c#, json, ajax, api

```
{"$id":"1","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$id":"2","Joueur":[{"$ref":"1"},{"$id":"3","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$ref":"2"},"Parametre":{"$id":"4","Joueur":[{"$ref":"1"},{"$ref":"3"},{"$id":"5","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$ref":"2"},"Parametre":{"$ref":"4"},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":15,"pseudoJoueur":"Jean-Louis","emailJoueur":"jl@moncul.com","pwdJoueur":"admin","idNiveauJoueur":1,"idParametre":1},{"$id":"6","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$ref":"2"},"Parametre":{"$ref":"4"},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":16,"pseudoJoueur":"Jean-Louis","emailJoueur":"jl@moncul.com","pwdJoueur":"admin","idNiveauJoueur":1,"idParametre":1},{"$id":"7","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$ref":"2"},"Parametre":{"$ref":"4"},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":17,"pseudoJoueur":"juan","emailJoueur":"juan@mail.com","pwdJoueur":"123","idNiveauJoueur":1,"idParametre":1},{"$id":"8","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$ref":"2"},"Parametre":{"$ref":"4"},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":18,"pseudoJoueur":"truc","emailJoueur":"truc@mail.com","pwdJoueur":"123","idNiveauJoueur":1,"idParametre":1},{"$id":"9","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$ref":"2"},"Parametre":{"$ref":"4"},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":19,"pseudoJoueur":"clafouti","emailJoueur":"clafouti@mail.com","pwdJoueur":"123","idNiveauJoueur":1,"idParametre":1},{"$id":"10","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$ref":"2"},"Parametre":{"$ref":"4"},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":20,"pseudoJoueur":"gerard bouchard","emailJoueur":"gerardbouchard@mail.com","pwdJoueur":"admin","idNiveauJoueur":1,"idParametre":1},{"$id":"11","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$ref":"2"},"Parametre":{"$ref":"4"},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":21,"pseudoJoueur":"Jean-Louis","emailJoueur":"jl@moncul.com","pwdJoueur":"123","idNiveauJoueur":1,"idParametre":1},{"$id":"12","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$ref":"2"},"Parametre":{"$ref":"4"},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":22,"pseudoJoueur":"jhon","emailJoueur":"jdoe@mail.com","pwdJoueur":"123","idNiveauJoueur":1,"idParametre":1}],"ParametreJoueur":[],"idParametre":1,"controleParametre":null,"niveauMusicParametre":1},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":14,"pseudoJoueur":"Jean-Louis","emailJoueur":"jl@moncul.com","pwdJoueur":"admin","idNiveauJoueur":1,"idParametre":1},{"$ref":"5"},{"$ref":"6"},{"$ref":"7"},{"$ref":"8"},{"$ref":"9"},{"$ref":"10"},{"$ref":"11"},{"$ref":"12"}],"idNiveauJoueur":1,"gradNiveauJoueur":"premiere pompe","numNiveauJoueur":1},"Parametre":{"$ref":"4"},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":3,"pseudoJoueur":"yan solo","emailJoueur":"yan@gmail.com","pwdJoueur":"1111","idNiveauJoueur":1,"idParametre":1},{"$id":"13","Aeronef":[{"$id":"14","Joueur":{"$ref":"13"},"TypeAeronef":{"$id":"15","Aeronef":[{"$ref":"14"},{"$id":"16","Joueur":{"$ref":"13"},"TypeAeronef":{"$ref":"15"},"idAeronef":2,"vieAeronef":100,"stockAeronef":0,"carburantAeronef":100,"degatAeronef":0,"niveauAeronef":4,"prixAeronef":8500,"idJoueur":4,"idTypeAeronef":1}],"idTypeAeronef":1,"nomTypeAeronef":"Enterprise"},"idAeronef":1,"vieAeronef":100,"stockAeronef":100,"carburantAeronef":100,"degatAeronef":0,"niveauAeronef":5,"prixAeronef":10500,"idJoueur":4,"idTypeAeronef":1},{"$ref":"16"}],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$id":"17","Joueur":[{"$ref":"13"}],"idNiveauJoueur":2,"gradNiveauJoueur":"caporal de l'espace","numNiveauJoueur":2},"Parametre":{"$id":"18","Joueur":[{"$ref":"13"}],"ParametreJoueur":[],"idParametre":2,"controleParametre":null,"niveauMusicParametre":2},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":4,"pseudoJoueur":"chubaka","emailJoueur":"chu@gmail.com","pwdJoueur":"2222","idNiveauJoueur":2,"idParametre":2},{"$id":"19","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$id":"20","Joueur":[{"$ref":"19"}],"idNiveauJoueur":4,"gradNiveauJoueur":"caporal chef de l'espace","numNiveauJoueur":3},"Parametre":{"$id":"21","Joueur":[{"$ref":"19"}],"ParametreJoueur":[],"idParametre":3,"controleParametre":null,"niveauMusicParametre":3},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":7,"pseudoJoueur":"rabbi jacob","emailJoueur":"rabbi@gmail.com","pwdJoueur":"3333","idNiveauJoueur":4,"idParametre":3},{"$id":"22","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$id":"23","Joueur":[{"$ref":"22"}],"idNiveauJoueur":5,"gradNiveauJoueur":"sergent de l'espace","numNiveauJoueur":4},"Parametre":{"$id":"24","Joueur":[{"$ref":"22"}],"ParametreJoueur":[],"idParametre":5,"controleParametre":null,"niveauMusicParametre":5},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":8,"pseudoJoueur":"jedi","emailJoueur":"jedi@gmail.com","pwdJoueur":"5555","idNiveauJoueur":5,"idParametre":5},{"$id":"25","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$id":"26","Joueur":[{"$ref":"25"}],"idNiveauJoueur":6,"gradNiveauJoueur":"sergent chef de l'espace","numNiveauJoueur":5},"Parametre":{"$id":"27","Joueur":[{"$ref":"25"}],"ParametreJoueur":[],"idParametre":6,"controleParametre":null,"niveauMusicParametre":6},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":9,"pseudoJoueur":"peat","emailJoueur":"peat@gmail.com","pwdJoueur":"6666","idNiveauJoueur":6,"idParametre":6},{"$id":"28","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$id":"29","Joueur":[{"$ref":"28"}],"idNiveauJoueur":7,"gradNiveauJoueur":"adjdantifrice","numNiveauJoueur":6},"Parametre":{"$id":"30","Joueur":[{"$ref":"28"}],"ParametreJoueur":[],"idParametre":7,"controleParametre":null,"niveauMusicParametre":7},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":10,"pseudoJoueur":"yoda","emailJoueur":"yoda@gmail.com","pwdJoueur":"7777","idNiveauJoueur":7,"idParametre":7},{"$id":"31","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$id":"32","Joueur":[{"$ref":"31"}],"idNiveauJoueur":8,"gradNiveauJoueur":"major de l'espace","numNiveauJoueur":7},"Parametre":{"$id":"33","Joueur":[{"$ref":"31"}],"ParametreJoueur":[],"idParametre":8,"controleParametre":null,"niveauMusicParametre":8},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":11,"pseudoJoueur":"leile","emailJoueur":"leila@gmail.com","pwdJoueur":"8888","idNiveauJoueur":8,"idParametre":8},{"$id":"34","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$id":"35","Joueur":[{"$ref":"34"}],"idNiveauJoueur":9,"gradNiveauJoueur":"lieutenant de la galaxie","numNiveauJoueur":8},"Parametre":{"$id":"36","Joueur":[{"$ref":"34"}],"ParametreJoueur":[],"idParametre":9,"controleParametre":null,"niveauMusicParametre":9},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":12,"pseudoJoueur":"diana","emailJoueur":"v@gmail.com","pwdJoueur":"9999","idNiveauJoueur":9,"idParametre":9},{"$id":"37","Aeronef":[],"Inventaire":[],"NiveauJoueur":{"$id":"38","Joueur":[{"$ref":"37"}],"idNiveauJoueur":10,"gradNiveauJoueur":"capitaine de l'univers","numNiveauJoueur":9},"Parametre":{"$id":"39","Joueur":[{"$ref":"37"}],"ParametreJoueur":[],"idParametre":10,"controleParametre":null,"niveauMusicParametre":10},"JoueurEnvironnement":[],"Messagerie":[],"ParametreJoueur":[],"Partie":[],"idJoueur":13,"pseudoJoueur":"xena","emailJoueur":"xena@gmail.com","pwdJoueur":"10","idNiveauJoueur":10,"idParametre":10},{"$ref":"3"},{"$ref":"5"},{"$ref":"6"},{"$ref":"7"},{"$ref":"8"},{"$ref":"9"},{"$ref":"10"},{"$ref":"11"},{"$ref":"12"}]
```

I want to do some request on a json created by my c# api with entity framework and I've have some problems with foreign key from my database

I've created a project mvc c# entity framework with visual studio 2019 then an api mvc in c# with entity framework the json is strange.I put those line in my apiwebconfig file in order to have a json from the api and not an xml but there is weird ref in the json

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

I just need to log in with an account I've created but only that account created directly in the database works for the log in.

Comment: Try it `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue(&quot;text/html&quot;) );`

Comment: the &quot;text/html&quot; are underline in red

Comment: I think my problem is in my webapiconfig, I don't find a good way to serialize json, any ideas

Comment: Please show your result

Comment: i put my json and at the end I have $ref:6 $ref:8 ... i think it's because of my foreign keys and the way i configure the json in my webapiconfig